# drupal filtered html filed alerting message

Tags: theming

I have a xss security issue in Drupal 6.

If I type an input field in HTML full mode like prompting something and after that just clicking on Filtered HTML mode, it's prompting me a message. This is not normal isn't ?

This is a youtube link to show you the problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UCO_Hmh1lg

What should I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers :) the current question is not very clear. Try including screenshots, exact steps (e.g. which field?) and details about the installation (e.g. which modules are you using? on which page is that field?). And most importantly - how do you know it's an XSS issue?

Comment: Hello, thank you :) I included a video on youtube instead of screenshots, all the details are there. It's an xss issue since we can insert code in the original one !

Comment: Got it now, thanks for clarifying :) what are your allowed HTML tags for `filtered_html` text format here: `admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html`? Also, this is not the right place to report potential security issues. See [this](https://drupal.org/security-team/report-issue) page for more information. It is very important that you do not make this public until it's fixed as it could compromise live websites.

Comment: what are your allowed HTML ? could you explain what do you mean ? does it mean why did I allow HTML tags for filtered_html ? If so, it's not me who did it, it was the webmaster before me ! Ok I made a report there.

Comment: Sorry, now I realized you were speaking about D6. The filter settings are here: `admin/settings/filters/1/configure` (assuming Filtered HTML has ID of 1). The list of allowed HTML tags is defined there. Also, I believe the tags will be shown only during editing, and will not be displayed when rendered on the front end. Try replicating the issue as a regular member without permissions for Full HTML and check if it's rendered with the alert on the front end. Btw, having Full HTML for regular users is dangerous scenario. If users already have Full HTML, they could do whatever they want.